# Are public university classrooms considered public space?

Tags: united-states, privacy

This question pertains to the USA. In all public universities I'm aware of, anyone can get on campus, sit in on virtually any lecture, and enter the school's library. Does this mean that public universities are considered public space? What about within a public university classroom? Do people have an expectation of privacy when in a public university classroom?

Comment: Does the former imply a lack of the latter?

Comment: Ah, I guess my question pertains more to direct examples, such as being able to photograph someone, or having other people end up in photos of yourself when in a public university classroom

Comment: Then ask that in a new question - don't edit your question to make existing answers incomplete

Comment: Fair enough, edit removed, original question still stands

Comment: Also, there are several questions on this site that address photography

Comment: I looked at those, I'm more looking at whether a public university falls under the definition of a public space. The photography edit was because some counter examples I was provided with were a bit abstract--such as the phone booth case, so I thought I'd specify

Answer (score 4):

No.  Just because some building is "owned by the public" or State, doesn't mean it's public property.

A state's national guard installation comes to mind immediately. State workers' offices are not public places.  Airport hangars/buildings/runways.  You can't just go hang out in the DPW garages.

Comment: Fair enough, but note that you CAN simply go hang out on most areas of a public university campus

Comment: @yaboi Only for lack of enforcement or by permission. A public university has the same authority over its property as a private landowner and they can and do have people removed from campus for trespassing. It isn't uncommon in big cities for all or parts of a public university campus to be actually gated.

Answer (score 1):

You must be a student enrolled in the class to (legally) attend it. A class is not "open to the public," and permission from the instructor must be given to "sit in" on a class. So yes, there is an expectation of privacy in the classroom, limited to only those enrolled or teaching in the current class in the current term.